# error in making box plot using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data file with 4 columns. but the number of rows for each
column is different. I want to make a box plot using a command like
this:

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point",
                              shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
```

but due diffent number of rows per column, it gives error. do you guys
know how to that?

Answer (score 1):

You should bring it to long form with something like `reshape` or `melt`. Then it shouldn't be a problem that tehre are a different number of observations for each group.

See this post: [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) with many examples.